# SSD Showing no signs of failure failed over weekend and is getting extremely hot to the touch

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd, dmesg

I have a 500GB Samsung 850 EVO, on Friday I had the workstation it was in powered on and idling. However this morning the tower was off, When I went to start it showed no boot devices. I booted to Ubuntu and I cannot even see the disk. dmesg is not reporting anything. I checked the SMART status weekly and all showed well, I had no file system errors and no issues with corrupt files. the R/W was not super intensive by any means. It was in a climate controlled building all weekend. Now, I really like the EVO disks as I have never had an issue with them. All prior SSD issues I had, had forewarning. The disk is less than 2 yeas old. Is there any reason this would happen? What can be done to prevent it? I also would like to add that by getting hot, it is almost unavoidable even through the case, that had never happened before today.

Comment: SSDs always fail unexpectedly, unlike the old HDDs.

Comment: Sounds like a random hardware failure. It just happens sometimes. You can't avoid it.

Comment: Probably under warranty....https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/support/warranty/

Comment: I have a 2 TB Samsung EVO 860 in my Lenovo ThinkCenter. I just took the side off and measured the SSD with an EXTECH IR meter. 25 degrees C and not hot. Boot with a bootable USB key and let it run. Does it still overheat